# Fixing a corrupted RAR-file

Tags: archiving, file-corruption, rar, winrar

I have a password protected RAR-file that I created using WinRAR. I wanted to add another file to it, however the way I did it ended up seemingly corrupting the file. Now if I open it and type in my password I get this:

```
!   E:\area51_record02-1.rar: Checksum error in the encrypted file E:\area51_record02-1.rar. Corrupt file or wrong password.
!   E:\area51_record02-1.rar: No files to extract
```

**So my question is, is there anyway to undo it?** Nothing I have done has worked. Extracting it while keeping broken files did nothing. WinRAR's repair did nothing. I tried using Recovery Toolbox for RAR which did nothing, it's just scanning *super* slowly and making no progress.

---

Now to exactly what I did. My RAR file has a bunch a folders and files in it. I opened it by double clicking it which doesn't extract it but opens it in inside of WinRAR. I then dragged my new file over into this window and everything appeared to be fine, I saw my file there and everything. When I closed the window however and tried to open it again I got the error message you see above. I do not have a backup of the RAR so I was hoping for a way to reverse what I did.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? I mean can you create a new encrypted rar file with a similar  directory structure inside, then copy it, open it and add a file inside in the same way you did? Check if the error rises again. Please [edit] your post adding the version of the program you used. ps> Welcome on SU.

Comment: @Hastur Thanks for helping me, I managed to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to reproduce the problem I noticed that everything worked fine. Though I did get the exact same error by simply typing in the password incorrectly. This was my mistake. Somehow I partly forgot the password right after adding that file making me think that adding the file was somehow to blame for this. After realizing this I tried another password and it worked.

I feel stupid now, but glad to see my files are still there :)

Comment: You may feel "stupid" , but others may do the same thing and this answer may help. +1